# Passing data forward with delegates and UITabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController in my application.

I am trying to pass data forward from the first tab to the second tab of my application. In the first tab I have a UITableViewController and in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method I have this code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [self.tabBarController.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    viewControllerB.array = self.filteredArray; 

    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

This code executes okay and takes me to the second tab of my UiTabBarController. However the `viewControllerB.array` property I am setting in viewControllerB is always nil and is never set.

I tried to use delegate pattern - but it seems that pattern is more suited to backwards data passing.

Where am I  going wrong? Also, could I use delegates to pass data forward?

**UPDATE - Solution found**

Per @Merlevedeless comment - the correct code is this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = navigationController.viewControllers[0]; 
    searchViewController.array = self.suggestedSearchArray; 

    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

I had to do this as viewControllerB is embedded inside a UINavigation Controller.

Comment: which property is always nil?  the "`array`" one?  Are you certain the "`viewControllerB`" object is not nil, when you set it's property?

Comment: Sorry I will update the answer to be clear. Yes, the viewControllerB.array property is always nil. I stepped through the method using the debugger and sure enough viewControllerB is initialised and is an instance of ViewControllerB class. Any ideas?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann It seems I had a brain fart - the viewControllerB object is nil. Why would this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't this

```
ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [self.tabBarController.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

be this?

```
ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. This worked - however I had to modify it. Updated my question.

Comment: Oh, I see, there was no way of knowing that your had a NavigationController in-between. :)

Comment: That's my fault for not being clear and disclosing that. Sorry!